# Inject inherited property values using CDI-Weld

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I'm developing a basic Swing application and, even if I always tend to use Spring Ioc (with xml configuration) for dependency injection I want to give a try to CDI-Weld. Having the following structure done in Spring, the container creates a `SchoolBoy` and a `UniversityStudent`, each one with its name.

```
public class Student{

    protected String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class SchoolBoy extends Student{

}

public class UniversityStudent extends Student{

}
```

```xml
<bean class="SchoolBoy">
    <property name="name" value="Daniel" />
</bean>

<bean class="UniversityStudent">
    <property name="name" value="Rose" />
</bean>
```

I've seen it's possible to do something similar in CDI using `@Inject @Config` annotations. However, every single time I see this, they're above the property itself and, being an inherited property, I cannot do that for my classes here. How do I achieve each `Student` subclass to get its own `name` value?

**UPDATE**

Injecting that values in subclasses doesn't necessarily mean hardcoding them in the configuration file. The property value itself can be acquired from a *.properties* file. However given the edge case that `Student` is into a legacy project and I want to innherit my classes from it and inject that property, what could the solution be?

Answer (score 1):

CDI currently doesn't support XML configuration natively. You have to use a library like [Solder](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/xml-provider.html) to achieve this. However it's a bad practice and strongly discouraged to set bean properties where you configure your dependency management (spring.xml) as this is not type and refactor safe. 
The other option is to use a producer method where you will set the needed value:

```
public SchoolBoy produceSchoolBoy {
   //construct new SchoolBoy() and set its name
}
```

and you will have a producer for the different Student types. Not very flexible but will work.

Comment: Does not necessarily mean I want to include the value directly. Could be a reference to a *.properties* file where the value is stored. However how to point to it if it's an `A` class **protected** field and `B` extends `A` when I want to use `B`?

Comment: Don't understand your second question. Could you explain it more deeply?

Comment: Create a producer method and set the property there

Comment: Ok, I'm taking a look. If you could provide code for my example it would be definitely the correct answer.